# get records from 10am to 4pm

Tags: mysql, time

Table: TeachersAvailableTime

```
ID | TeacherID | Day    | startTime | endTime     
1  | 1         | Mon    | 09:00:00  | 12:00:00    
2  | 1         | Tue    | 09:00:00  | 16:00:00   
3  | 1         | Wed    | 09:00:00  | 14:00:00    
4  | 1         | Thu    | 09:00:00  | 12:00:00    
5  | 1         | Fri    | 09:00:00  | 16:00:00    
6  | 1         | Sat    | 09:00:00  | 14:00:00    
7  | 1         | Sun    | 11:00:00  | 16:00:00    
8  | 2         | Mon    | 11:00:00  | 12:00:00    
9  | 3         | Tue    | 12:00:00  | 13:00:00    
10 | 4         | Wed    | 10:00:00  | 16:00:00
```

I have a teachers available time table and want to get those all teacher who are available on Sat at 10am.

I tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM working_times WHERE startTime >= '10:00:00' AND endTime <= '16:00:00'
```

but it fails in cases like In this query if I add `startTime >= '10:00:00' AND day='Mon'` then it is not works correctly, because Teacher 1 is available at 10:00:00 and same issue with endTime

Comment: A complete redesign of your database would be the best solution. Remember a SQL table is not like a diagram on a piece of paper

Comment: Storing times as text makes it harder to query. MySQL has built-in functions for this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: And nor is a database table a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Huh. You have bad mySql stucture.

```
ID | TeacherID | Day    | startTime | endTime     
1  | 1         | Mon    | 09:00:00  | 16:00:00    
2  | 1         | Tue    | 09:00:00  | 16:00:00   
3  | 1         | Wed    | 09:00:00  | 16:00:00    
4  | 1         | Thu    | 09:00:00  | 16:00:00    
5  | 1         | Fri    | 09:00:00  | 16:00:00    
6  | 1         | Sat    | 09:00:00  | 16:00:00    
7  | 1         | Sun    | 11:00:00  | 16:00:00    
8  | 2         | Mon    | 11:00:00  | 16:00:00    
9  | 3         | Tue    | 12:00:00  | 16:00:00    
10 | 4         | Wed    | 10:00:00  | 16:00:00
```

This is query to create table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `working_times` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `teacherID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `day` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
 `startTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `endTine` time DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

Now you can use this query

```
SELECT * FROM working_times WHERE startTime >= '10:00:00' AND endTime <= '16:00:00'
```

Comment: In this query if I add **startTime >= '10:00:00' AND day='Mon'**  then it is not works correctly b/c **Teacher 1** is available at 10:00:00 @BCM

Comment: Same issue with endTime  @BCM